# Cant find the string "AutoOpen" in a macro enabled Word document

Tags: strings, yara

So, I was testing a Yara rule which goes like this:

```
rule macro_auto_run

{
    meta:
        description = "Document with macro that auto runs"
        
    strings:
        $s1 = "AutoOpen"
        $s2 = "Workbook_Open"
        
    condition:
        ($s1 or $s2)
}
```

I created a Word file, then created a macro in the document with the name, AutoOpen, put some code in it and attempted to test it against this rule.

It did not trigger. Then I ran the utility `strings` on it. It couldn't find the word "AutoOpen". Used another hex editor like HxD, still nothing. Did a Unicode, Ascii search for the string as well. Nothing! I am wondering why.

Edit: Figured out that I need to unzip the archive and then search within those files.

Comment: which version of Word?  Newer ones are zip files which would need unpacking first.

Comment: Ok. It is the OOXML based version.